# Volume Scatter is changing colour

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, color, volumetrics

I want to add fog to a blender scene (in Cycles), so I created a cube and applied a Volume Scatter Shader. I changed the color to white, but the cube is black now.

When I change the color to red, it's becoming blue.

How can I change the settings so Blender is rendering the color that is shown in my Volume Scatter Node?

[image: black fog]

[image: fog has the wrong color]

Answer (score 4):

If the cube is black make sure the Anisotropic value is set to 0 (zero). To make the fog a consistent colour, add an 'Add Shader' and a 'Volume Absorption Shader' with the same colour as the Volume scatter node.

[image: Volume Scatter Only]

[image: Volume Scatter + Absorption]

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but the Anisotropic Value was already set to 0, and the Volume Absorption Shader does not work ...

Comment: From the looks of your scene there doesn't seem to be a light source. Try adding a lamp or a mesh light. Also I see you're using an older version of blender. Try upgrading to the lastest one.